# Recreating the Cura "fuzzy Skin" effect on a model

Tags: texturing, faces

I'm attempting to make a hand grip that will be 3D printed and fitted to the the brim of a cable drum.

I want to create a rough surface on specific faces. I would normally use the "Fuzzy Skin" setting in my slicer (Cura fork) to do this, but in this instance everything must be modeled, and not added in process or post process.

What is the best way to replicate the effect on the faces marked in green only, and how can I achieve this affect?

[image]

I am aware you can create a textured surface using bump maps or sculpting brushes, or similar techniques, but this isn't something that I have any experience of as I haven't touched on this area of blender before and so don't really understand even the most basic elements of it.

Comment: you need to create the pattern manually then deform it into your surfaces , or create or download alpha maps and use it with displacement modifier

Comment: Right now, I don't know how to apply one, let alone create one.